# Cant add column with out dropping table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, ddl, alter-table

I have a production table that has 100 million rows , and for a reporting purpose we need to add one additional column which will be a Numeric (18,0).Obviously SQL won't let me add that column with out dropping the table.Any other way that i can do this with out affecting the data?

Comment: It should be fine to add it if you do it via `alter table`. If you're using the designer, and *especially if you're trying to "position" it anywhere other than as the last column* then the designer may choose to drop/create.

Answer (score 8):

You can add a column without dropping the table.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD  SomeColumnName NUMERIC(18,0)
```

**UPDATE**

If you want the column `NOT NULL` then you'll have to make it accept NULL first, then set the values through an update, and lastly alter the column to `NOT NULL`.

Or set a default value such as

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD SomeColumnName DECIMAL(18,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
```

Comment: That's it? if that wont drop my table and only adds the new column i would be happy.Will give it a shot! Thanks

Comment: i tried, but the result is the same....when i run such a statment ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD  SomeColumnName NUMERIC(18,0) it threw an error                                  Msg 4901, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER TABLE only allows columns to be added that can contain nulls, or have a DEFAULT definition specified, 
or the column being added is an identity or timestamp column, or 
alternatively if none of the previous conditions are satisfied the table must be empty to allow addition of this column....

Comment: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[obligations_monthend_snapshots]
    ADD [417_number] Numeric(18,0) NOT NULL

Comment: i am pretty new here and i need more reputation to be able to join chats a guess.

Comment: @SQLHunter Please see updated answer.

Comment: I have added the column with a default value 0.and when i do my insert which is about 2.5 million records the value on that column is 0.Now what i need is to remove the default constraint and make the column NOT NULL so that it can accept regular record.